# What is a sacrificial agent?

Tags: synthesis, catalysis

I came across this reading a journal article. Here I have the context:

> Here we report for the first time the synthesis of $\ce{TiO2}$ NPs
>   on a layered $\ce{MoS2}$/graphene (MG) hybrid for use in
>   photocatalytic H2 production. It is shown that the activity of
>   the $\ce{TiO2}$ NPs is significantly enhanced by the presence of this
>   layered MG cocatalyst. In this case, ethanol was used as a
>   **sacrificial agent**, as it is a sustainable and renewable source and
>   showed very good performance with this photocatalyst;
>   however, other **sacrificial agents** (e.g., glycerol) can be used
>   to make this strategy feasible.

Google results came up with similar instances.

My guess is that it would be a chemical consumed in a reaction, but one that doesn't contribute to the structure of the product. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sacrificial agent" usually refers to something variable, but with little value, that can be used to produce something specific or carry out a specific function. In this case, an alcohol (ethanol or glycerol) is sacrificed to act as a source of hydrogen gas, while the titanium species is a catalyst that is activated by light to allow generation of hydrogen.